# Akka cluster slave can't join seeds

Tags: akka.net

I'm trying to build a small AKka.NET Cluster Application but I'm having problems since I keep getting the following error:

```
[WARNING][7/14/2022 10:42:06 AM][Thread 0011][akka.tcp://accountsystem@localhost:57959/system/cluster/core/daemon/joinSeedNodeProcess-1] Couldn't join seed nodes after [2] attempts, will try again. seed-nodes=[akka.tcp://accountsystem@localhost:2551]
```

This is my docker-compose file for my lighthouse service:

```
version: '3'

services:
  accountsystem.lighthouse:
    image: petabridge/lighthouse:latest
    hostname: accountsystem.lighthouse
    ports:
      - '2551:2551'
    environment:
      ACTORSYSTEM: "accountsystem"
      CLUSTER_PORT: 2551
      CLUSTER_IP: "accountsystem.lighthouse"
      CLUSTER_SEEDS: "akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551"
```

And this is my AKka.NET configuration:

```
 <![CDATA[
          akka {
            actor {
              provider = cluster
            }
            
            remote {
              log-remote-lifecycle-events = DEBUG
              dot-netty.tcp {
                hostname = "localhost"
                port = 0
              }
            }

            cluster {
              seed-nodes = [
                "akka.tcp://accountsystem@localhost:2551"]

              #auto-down-unreachable-after = 30s
            }
          }
      ]]>
```

Also I am sharing my code setup for my `AKkaService`:

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var akkaConfig = (AkkaConfigurationSection) System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("akka");
    var bootstrap = BootstrapSetup.Create()
        .WithConfig(akkaConfig.AkkaConfig) 
        .WithActorRefProvider(ProviderSelection.Cluster.Instance); // launch Akka.Cluster
    

    // enable DI support inside this ActorSystem, if needed
    var diSetup = DependencyResolverSetup.Create(_serviceProvider);

    // merge this setup (and any others) together into ActorSystemSetup
    var actorSystemSetup = bootstrap.And(diSetup);

    // start ActorSystem
    _actorSystem = ActorSystem.Create("accountsystem", actorSystemSetup);
    var props = DependencyResolver.For(_actorSystem).Props<AccountRouterActor>();
    _actorRef = _actorSystem.ActorOf(props, "account");
    _actorSystem.WhenTerminated.ContinueWith(tr => {
        _applicationLifetime.StopApplication();
    });

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I have been reading about actor system and server mismatch, but I think the name is correct which would be `accountsystem`. I am also sharing my console after starting up my docker compose file with all the messages. Maybe that will help.

```
docker-compose up
WARNING: Found orphan containers (accountpoc_mssql_1, mysql) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Starting accountpoc_accountsystem.lighthouse_1 ... done
Attaching to accountpoc_accountsystem.lighthouse_1
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [Docker-Bootstrap] IP=accountsystem.lighthouse
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [Docker-Bootstrap] PORT=2551
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [Docker-Bootstrap] SEEDS=["akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551"]
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [Lighthouse] ActorSystem: accountsystem; IP: accountsystem.lighthouse; PORT: 2551
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [Lighthouse] Performing pre-boot sanity check. Should be able to parse address [akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551]
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [Lighthouse] Parse successful.
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [INFO][07/14/2022 10:52:48][Thread 0001][remoting (akka://accountsystem)] Starting remoting
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [INFO][07/14/2022 10:52:48][Thread 0001][remoting (akka://accountsystem)] Remoting started; listening on addresses : [akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551]
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [INFO][07/14/2022 10:52:48][Thread 0001][remoting (akka://accountsystem)] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551]
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [INFO][07/14/2022 10:52:48][Thread 0001][Cluster (akka://accountsystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551] - Starting up...
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [INFO][07/14/2022 10:52:48][Thread 0001][Cluster (akka://accountsystem)] Cluster Node [1.6.2] - Node [akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551] is JOINING itself (with roles [lighthouse], version [1.6.2]) and forming a new cluster
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [INFO][07/14/2022 10:52:48][Thread 0001][Cluster (akka://accountsystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551] - is the new leader among reachable nodes (more leaders may exist)
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [INFO][07/14/2022 10:52:48][Thread 0001][Cluster (akka://accountsystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551] - Leader is moving node [akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551] to [Up]
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [INFO][07/14/2022 10:52:49][Thread 0001][Cluster (akka://accountsystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551] - Started up successfully
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [INFO][07/14/2022 10:52:49][Thread 0001][akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551/user/petabridge.cmd] petabridge.cmd host bound to [0.0.0.0:9110]
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [ERROR][07/14/2022 10:52:58][Thread 0008][akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2Faccountsystem%40localhost%3A59968-1/endpointWriter] Dropping message [Akka.Actor.ActorSelectionMessage] for non-local recipient [[akka.tcp://accountsystem@localhost:2551/]] arriving at [akka.tcp://accountsystem@localhost:2551] inbound addresses [akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551]
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [ERROR][07/14/2022 10:53:02][Thread 0008][akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2Faccountsystem%40localhost%3A59968-1/endpointWriter] Dropping message [Akka.Actor.ActorSelectionMessage] for non-local recipient [[akka.tcp://accountsystem@localhost:2551/]] arriving at [akka.tcp://accountsystem@localhost:2551] inbound addresses [akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551]
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [ERROR][07/14/2022 10:53:08][Thread 0008][akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2Faccountsystem%40localhost%3A59968-1/endpointWriter] Dropping message [Akka.Actor.ActorSelectionMessage] for non-local recipient [[akka.tcp://accountsystem@localhost:2551/]] arriving at [akka.tcp://accountsystem@localhost:2551] inbound addresses [akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551]
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [WARNING][07/14/2022 10:53:10][Thread 0008][akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2Faccountsystem%40localhost%3A59968-1] Association with remote system akka.tcp://accountsystem@localhost:59968 has failed; address is now gated for 5000 ms. Reason is: [Akka.Remote.EndpointDisassociatedException: Disassociated
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter.PublishAndThrow(Exception reason, LogLevel level, Boolean needToThrow)
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter.Unhandled(Object message)
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Actor.UntypedActor.Receive(Object message)
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Actor.ActorBase.AroundReceive(Receive receive, Object message)
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.ReceiveMessage(Object message)
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.ReceivedTerminated(Terminated t)
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.AutoReceiveMessage(Envelope envelope)
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.Invoke(Envelope envelope)]
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | [ERROR][07/14/2022 10:53:10][Thread 0008][akka://accountsystem/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2Faccountsystem%40localhost%3A59968-1/endpointWriter] Disassociated
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  | Cause: Akka.Remote.EndpointDisassociatedException: Disassociated
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter.PublishAndThrow(Exception reason, LogLevel level, Boolean needToThrow)
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter.Unhandled(Object message)
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Actor.UntypedActor.Receive(Object message)
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Actor.ActorBase.AroundReceive(Receive receive, Object message)
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.ReceiveMessage(Object message)
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.ReceivedTerminated(Terminated t)
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.AutoReceiveMessage(Envelope envelope)
accountsystem.lighthouse_1  |    at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.Invoke(Envelope envelope)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just had to change the hocon configuration to the following:

```
 <![CDATA[
          akka {
            actor {
              provider = cluster
            }
            
            remote {
              log-remote-lifecycle-events = DEBUG
              dot-netty.tcp {
                hostname = "localhost"
                port = 2551
              }
            }

            cluster {
              seed-nodes = [
                "akka.tcp://accountsystem@localhost:2551"]

              #auto-down-unreachable-after = 30s
            }
          }
      ]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for these environment variables to work:

```
   CLUSTER_PORT: 2551
   CLUSTER_IP: "accountsystem.lighthouse"
   CLUSTER_SEEDS: "akka.tcp://accountsystem@accountsystem.lighthouse:2551"
```

You'll need to install https://github.com/petabridge/akkadotnet-bootstrap/tree/dev/src/Akka.Bootstrap.Docker and call `BootstrapFromDocker()` on your `Config` object. That's what Lighthouse is doing internally.

You might also find using [Akka.Cluster.Hosting](https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Hosting) to be an easier way of doing this since you can now extract those values from a typed Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration section and pass them in programmatically to the `WithRemoting` and `WithClustering` methods ala:

```
builder.Services.AddAkka("MyActorSystem", configurationBuilder =>
{
    configurationBuilder
        .WithRemoting("localhost", 8110)
        .WithClustering(new ClusterOptions(){ Roles = new[]{ "myRole" },
            SeedNodes = new[]{ Address.Parse("akka.tcp://MyActorSystem@localhost:8110")}})
        .WithActors((system, registry) =>
    {
        var echo = system.ActorOf(act =>
        {
            act.ReceiveAny((o, context) =>
            {
                context.Sender.Tell($"{context.Self} rcv {o}");
            });
        }, "echo");
        registry.TryRegister<Echo>(echo); // register for DI
    });
});
```